# Avoiding extraneous solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, quadratics

When solving quadratic equations like $\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1} = \sqrt{2x + 1}$  we are told to solve naively, for example we would get $x \in \{\frac{-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\}$, even though the first solution doesn't work, and then try all the solutions and eliminate the extraneous ones. This is not a very elegant algorithm! How would one use the fact that $\sqrt{x}^2= |x|$ to avoid having to check answers?

Comment: Do you really consider methods that solve absolute value equations to be more elegant than testing for extraneous solutions?

Comment: I thought maybe there was an elegant way to do it without checking solutions.

Comment: There are many questions here at MathSE on solving absolute value equations. These can be fairly tricky to solve and usually involve checking multiple possibilities. I personally consider checking for extraneous solutions to be easier to understand and to do.

Comment: why is not checking is elegant? in fact you just have the faith that whatever the method you applied is correct.there is no reason not to error check the answers. it should be part of problem solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ensure that
$$
\begin{cases}
x+1\ge0\\
x-1\ge0\\
2x+1\ge0
\end{cases}
$$
then you can square both sides, because they are guaranteed to exist and, when $a,b\ge0$, $a=b$ if and only if $a^2=b^2$.

The conditions above are equivalent to $x\ge1$.

Squaring we get
$$
x+1+2\sqrt{x^2-1}+x-1=2x+1
$$
that simplifies to
$$
2\sqrt{x^2-1}=1
$$
and you can square again, because both sides are non negative. This gives
$$
4x^2=5.
$$
Since you know that $x\ge1$, the only solution is
$$
x=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$

Comment: So in general I would just calculate the domain of the original equation and apply that to my solution set?

Comment: @RenéG You must be careful also in the intermediate passages before squaring, because one side might be negative.

Comment: @RenéG Your proposed correction is wrong: $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is defined (because $x\ge1$) and nonnegative by definition.

Comment: Then what did you mean by "you can square again, because both sides are non-negative"?

Comment: @RenéG The same as before: when $a,b\ge0$, the equality $a=b$ is the same as $a^2=b^2$ (you don't add extraneous solutions, in other words).

Comment: That's also true for $a,b \leq 0$. And since $a = b$ they have to be both negative, both positive, or both zero. So why make that note?

Comment: @RenéG You said it: you have to ensure both sides have the same sign, before squaring. Of course, they also must be defined, but in the second squaring that was already granted, because $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is the product of two terms we already know to exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try to square both sides.

$$ \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1} = \sqrt{2x+1} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \left ( \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1} \right )^{2} = \left ( \sqrt{2x+1} \right )^{2} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow  \left ( \sqrt{x+1} \right )^2 + 2\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x-1} + \left ( \sqrt{x-1} \right )^2 = 2x+1 $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (x+1) + 2\sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)} + (x-1) = 2x+1 \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)} = \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (x+1)(x-1) = \frac{1}{4} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow x^{2} - 1 - \frac{1}{4} = 0 \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow x^{2} - \frac{5}{4} = 0 $$

And now you can just use the quadratic formula.

$$ x = \frac{-(0)\pm \sqrt{(0)^2-4(1)(-\frac{5}{4}})}{2(1)} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow x = \frac{\pm \sqrt{4\times \frac{5}{4}}}{2} \Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow x = \frac{\pm \sqrt{5}}{2} $$

Also, $ -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} $ is not included in the final solution, try to see why...

I hope I have helped. Saclyr.